# Receiving email on a fresh new Debian

Tags: debian, email, dns, postfix

I re-installed a fresh clean Debian 8 on my VPS.

All is set up to default values.

`dpkg -s exim4` and `dpkg -s postfix` says that exim *is not* installed, and that postfix *is* installed. This is confirmed by `lsof -i :25` which shows a PID 478, then `ps p 478` shows `478 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master`.
I haven't done `apt-get install postfix`, it seems that it has been installed by default.

I've already done a DNS MX record for `example.com` by my registrar, directing it my server.

I just sent an email from my Gmail to `root@example.com`.

1. I still see `No mail` when doing `$ mail`.
2. How to see if something has arrived to postfix?
3. Is there a configuration to do on a fresh new Debian install to accept emails from internet?
4. Should I create the mailbox `root` locally, to accept mail arriving from external mailers to `root@example.com`?

---

Here is the result of `iptables` (unmodified, default configuration):

```
root@blah:~# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 77135 packets, 50M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 120 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 66416 packets, 11M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I see now in `cat /var/log/mail.log` this:

```
Nov 22 11:57:32 blah postfix/smtpd[10485]: connect from mail-ua0-f171.google.com[209.85.xxx.xxx]  
Nov 22 11:57:32 blah postfix/smtpd[10485]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-ua0-f171.google.com[209.85.xxx.xxx]: 454 4.7.1 <root@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user@gmail.com> to=<root@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-ua0-f171.google.com>  
Nov 22 11:57:32 blah postfix/smtpd[10485]: disconnect from mail-ua0-f171.google.com[209.85.xxx.xxx]
```

Comment: @roaima I added this to the question.

Comment: @roaima some news (see edit2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line contains the useful information that you need

> ```
> Nov 22 11:57:32 blah postfix/smtpd[10485]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from  mail-ua0-f171.google.com[209.85.xxx.xxx]: 454 4.7.1 <root@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user@gmail.com> to=<root@example.com ...
> ```

What this is telling you is that your machine is refusing to relay a message from Google to root@example.com. Now, you know that your machine is example.com, but clearly your machine doesn't.

Solution: modify the local configuration to include example.com as a name for your local machine. There is an easy-to-read document available on the Postfix website (((BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html)[http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination]) that explains how to set this up:

> **My own domain name**
>
> The mydomain parameter specifies the parent domain of $myhostname. By
>   default, it is derived from $myhostname by stripping off the first
>   part (unless the result would be a top-level domain).
>
> Conversely, if you specify mydomain in main.cf, then Postfix will use
>   its value to generate a fully-qualified default value for the
>   myhostname parameter.
>
> Examples (specify only one of the following):
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     mydomain = local.domain
>     mydomain = virtual.domain (virtual interface)
> ```
>
> **What domains to receive mail for**
>
> The mydestination parameter specifies what domains this machine will
>   deliver locally, instead of forwarding to another machine. The default
>   is to receive mail for the machine itself. See the VIRTUAL_README file
>   for how to configure Postfix for hosted domains.
>
> You can specify zero or more domain names, "/file/name" patterns
>   and/or "type:table" lookup tables (such as hash:, btree:, nis:, ldap:,
>   or mysql:), separated by whitespace and/or commas. A "/file/name"
>   pattern is replaced by its contents; "type:table" requests that a
>   table lookup is done and merely tests for existence: the lookup result
>   is ignored.
>
> IMPORTANT: If your machine is a mail server for its entire domain, you
>   must list $mydomain as well.
>
> Example 1: default setting.
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
> ```
>
> Example 2: domain-wide mail server.
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
> ```
>
> Example 3: host with multiple DNS A records.
>
> ```
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>     mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost 
>         www.$mydomain ftp.$mydomain
> ```
>
> Caution: in order to avoid mail delivery loops, you must list all
>   hostnames of the machine, including $myhostname, and
>   localhost.$mydomain.

So, this should be sufficient:

```
mydomain = example.com
...
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `mydestination = .... mydomain.com`  and now the error has disappeared, thanks :) But I get this `Nov 22 13:12:37 blah postfix/local[11526]: EEA343FC4: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=2.8, delays=0.88/0.4/0/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Nov 22 13:12:37 blah postfix/qmgr[11501]: EEA343FC4: removed`, and I still see nothing when doing `$ mail`.

Comment: I accepted your answer @roaima, I also added this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406399/59989

Answer (score 0):

In addition to roaima's answer, this solved it:

1. Add the domain name at the end of `mydestination = <....>, mydomain.com` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
2. Comment out this line: `#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"`
3. Then send an email from Gmail to `root@mydomain.com`, wait a few seconds
4. Do `mail`, you will see the new email :)